# Form with variable input values PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a form which has variable input values .For example  one customer has bought 5 items so all of them show another customer has bought 3 items so only three items show up.All these values are based on database

```
<form id="customer" class="customer" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="customer1" value="" > 
    <input type="text" name="customer2" value="" > 
    <input type="text" name="customer3" value="" > 
</form>
```

Now my question how do i process a form like this where every time the number of post variables is different.

Comment: Thanks I got the point , appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="text" name="customer[]" value="" >`

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$products = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    array_push($products, $key, $value);
}
```